# Как блоки разместить в таком порядке?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, разместил блоки в необходимом мне порядке, но этот способ мне не позволяет дальше обрабатывать этот кусок кода полноценно из классов DIV, как можно сверстать это по другому?
2 строки по 3 блока на всю ширину страницы, и при уменьшении страницы до размера телефона, блоки должны встававать друг под друга

```html
<div class="row" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
    <div class="col-md-4"  style="float:left; width: 20%; height:500px; background-image: url('/static/rock1.jpg');background-size: cover;">
     <div class="content_rock"style="margin-top:50%;"><font size="6" face="arial black">С заботой о ваших клиентах</font>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"  style="float:left; width: 100%; height:500px; background-image: url('/static/rock2.jpg'); background-size: cover; ">
      <div class="content_rock"style="margin-top:50%;"><font size="6" face="arial black">С заботой о ваших клиентах</font></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"  style="float:left; width: 100%; height:500px; background-image: url('/static/rock3.jpg'); background-size: cover; ">
      <div class="content_rock"style="margin-top:50%;"><font size="6" face="arial black">С заботой о ваших клиентах</font></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="col-md-4"  style="float:left; width:100%; height:500px; background-image: url('/static/rock5.jpg'); background-size: cover;  ">
      <div class="content_rock"style="margin-top:50%;"><font size="6" face="arial black">С заботой о ваших клиентах</font></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4"  style="float:left; width:100%; height:500px; background-image: url('/static/rock4.jpg'); background-size: cover; ">
      <div class="content_rock"style="margin-top:50%;"><font size="6" face="arial black">С заботой о ваших клиентах</font></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4"  style="float:left; width:100%; height:500px; background-image: url('/static/rock6.jpg'); background-size: cover; ">
      <div class="content_rock"style="margin-top:50%;"><font size="6" face="arial black">С заботой о ваших клиентах</font></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Уточните, что означает "полноценно обрабатывать" и как вам их нужно обрабатывать, *дополнив вопрос*

Comment: Чтобы классы не назывались как сетка bootstrap, так как здеь решение именно с помощью неё

Comment: Да, нужно без бутстрапа
Желательно через GRID или FlexBox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Flex:**

```css
* {margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

*И открываем на всю страницу*

**Grid:**

```css
* {margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

*И открываем на всю страницу*

**inline-block:**

```css
* {margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

*И открываем на всю страницу*

Comment: Прекрасное решение, а возможно в методе ГРИТ чтолбы они были как будто склеены, то есть без разрывов между ними?

Comment: Аж на выбор )))

Answer (score 0):

Задайте дополнительные классы блокам, вынесите стили в отдельный css